# Python socket 10048 error

Tags: python, sockets

I am learning network and for some reason I get an error with the bind line and I do not see why, help?

```
Server_Socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
Server_Socket.bind(('127.0.0.1', 80))
Server_Socket.listen(10)
```

Comment: Do you have another webserver or program running on your machine that may be using that port?

Comment: @DarnellMartin I have other computer which my siblings use, how can I see if they are may be using this port?

Comment: Try changing the port number from 80 to 8080 and check if it still gives you an error.

Comment: @DarnellMartin Thank you, it was to port :)

Answer (score 2):

In case someone comes across this error in the future, this exception is typically thrown in the event that another program is already bound to that port. Try changing the port from a popular port i.e(80,443,161..etc) to something above 1024 to be "safe" not to interfere with any other programs.